# Showing or refuting that not exists cyclic quotients of order 4 in $D_4$

Tags: group-theory

why not exists cyclic quotients of order 4 in $D_4$?

I have this: Let $H$ subgroup of $D_4$ with $|H|=2$. If $D_4/H$ is cyclic then

$|D_4/H|=4$ therefore $H\simeq \mathbb{Z}/{2\mathbb{Z}}\simeq Z(D_4)$ (because $|Z(D_4)|=2)$ then $D_4/H\simeq D_4/Z(D_4)$ cyclic then $D_4$ abelian, a contradiction.
This is correct?

Comment: $D_4$ is a simple and interesting group. [See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912773/calculate-quotients-of-mathbb-s-3-and-mathbb-d-4?rq=1) to understand its all possible quotients.

Answer (score 3):

Just because two subgroups of a group are isomorphic, doesn't mean that they give isomorphic quotients!

There are a few subgroups of order 2 in $D_4.$ There are $\{1, s\}, \{1, r^2s\},$ and $\{1, r^2\}.$

Quotienting by the first, you just get the cyclic group of order 4. By what happens if you quotient by the last?

You're setting $r^2 = 1.$ Your elements are $1, r, r^2, r^3, s, rs, r^2s, r^3s.$ These become $1, r, s, rs.$ This is not cyclic! Each element has order 2 in this quotient!

Comment: But then there would be a cyclic quotient of order 4 but I understand that there are no cyclic quotient of order 4.
 I'm confused.

Comment: There are two different quotients of order 4. One is cyclic. One is non-cyclic. There are two!

Comment: ´Why $D_4/<s>$ is cyclic? I have this:
$D_4/<s>=\left\{ \left\{e,s\right\},\left\{r,rs\right\},\left\{r^2,r^2s\right\},\left\{r^3,r^3s\right\}\right\}$ but I don't see that this is cyclic.

Comment: @MichaelBarz: I don't think that $\{1, s\}$ and $\{1, r^2s\}$ are normal in $D_4.$